# What type of photography sells well to business?

Tags: business, selling, promotion

My question is really aimed at anyone who has an opinion or has experience selling prints to business. I focus mainly on urban landscape photography in London and want to focus on selling my framed prints/artwork to businesses.

I have a company website that will be released in the next few days but I am interested in finding out what type of photography sells well to businesses. For example I tend to take a mixture of evening and black and white photography, I would imagine that in a business setting the black and white framed prints might sell better than the coloured/evening prints.

What are your opinions? I guess it may depend upon the company type that I am selling my artwork too. I would imagine that the financial/legal sector may appreciate b&w where as the creative sector may look more at the creative evening photography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there are a few too many variables here to be able to give a specific answer, but I will share some thoughts based on personal experience.

There's always the personal choice of somebody who's in charge of buying these prints; and as anyone who's ever tried to sell prints or exhibited knows that's a whole minefield, one which I'll certainly never decipher.

But more importantly, I find a lot of businesses seem to want imagery which I associated with the area in which they operate

I have sold [this image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/tm_photog/4257538787/) to an estate agent chain in the vicinity of this bridge (Runcorn, UK).

I've also sold images from [this series](http://www.flickr.com/photos/tm_photog/3490792622/in/photostream) to a legal firm, again close to the area where the images were taken (Liverpool, UK).

I have friends who have sold images to architects firms of projects they have completed, and one who has made quite a number of sales of images of the building an organisation occupies.

My advice would be to have a wide portfolio of images of varying styles to show to prospective customers, and if you're trying to sell framed prints to have the ability to adapt the framing to your customer's requirements.

Comment: Hi, it was my thinking as well that in terms of business I would imagine local images do sell well. Do you have any idea if black and white sell better than coloured images?

Comment: Personally I don't feel that there's any bias other than the choice of the buyer or a brief. I've sold more colour images lately for this purpose, but 10 years ago I was taking and selling more B&W images. Be flexible and adapt :)